# psbarcode results in bar codes of different rotation on linux vs. windows environments

Tags: windows, linux, pst-barcode

I'm using `psbarcode` to generate a `code39` bar code and I've encountered something odd, which I wondering if someone can shed some light on.

I'm using a combination of LaTeX and Velocity.

```
\begin{pspicture}
    %\psbarcode[rotate=90]{${workTicketId}}{includetext height=0.375}{code39} % Windows environment
    \psbarcode{${workTicketId}}{includetext height=0.375}{code39} % Linux environment
\end{pspicture}
```

Of the above two lines, the first one *Windows environment*, which is currently commented out -  I found that I had to rotate the bar code by 90 degrees in order for it to appear horizontal, but that same code would result in a vertical bar code on a Linux environment when compiled.

The second line, *Linux environment*, removing the rotation resulted in a bar code that was horizontal on a Linux environment, but a vertical environment when compiled in a Windows environment.

Now, I can code around the differences, but I would like to know if anyone else has encountered this before or if anyone has a reason for this behavior, and ideally I rather not code around the different operating systems if possible.

The follow are the packages included in my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This one works well under Linux:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{tikz}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
\fi
\begin{document}
foo
%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-5mm)(2.5in,0.4in)
    \psbarcode{AB123456}{includetext height=0.375}{code39} 
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4in,0)(5mm,2.5in)
    \psbarcode[rotate=90]{AB123456}{includetext height=0.375}{code39}
\end{pspicture}
%
bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

And running this on windows with `xelatex` gives the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
foo
%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-5mm)(2.5in,0.4in)
    \psbarcode{AB123456}{includetext height=0.375}{code39} 
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.4in,0)(5mm,2.5in)
    \psbarcode[rotate=90]{AB123456}{includetext height=0.375}{code39}
\end{pspicture}
%
bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't really address what I asked. Now, I find that pdflatex work well under both linux and windows and I have coded around the barcode rotation by simply checking the operating system I am running on. What I really want to know is the reason for this behavior, accounting for the behavior is easy. For instance, using java code I can determine if the report is being compiled on Windows with System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows"); and then I can adjust the rotation.